# Illegal offset type UPDATE ERROR in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

```
  public function update(UpdateStageRequest $request,  $parameterString)
    {
        $parameters = explode(',', $parameterString);

        $element_pedagogique_id = $parameters[0];
        $axe_stage_id = $parameters[1];
        $individu_id = $parameters[2];
        $encadrant_id = $parameters[3];
        $annee_universitaire_id = $parameters[4];
        $session_id = $parameters[5];
        $stage = Stage::where([
            'element_pedagogique_id' => $element_pedagogique_id,
            'axe_stage_id' => $axe_stage_id,
            'individu_id' => $individu_id,
            'encadrant_id' => $encadrant_id,
            'annee_universitaire_id' => $annee_universitaire_id,
            'session_id' => $session_id,
        ])->first();

        $stage->sujet = $request->input('sujet');
        $stage->evaluationEse = $request->input('evaluationEse');
        $stage->appreciationEncad = $request->input('appreciationEncad');
        $stage->noteEse = $request->input('noteEse');
        $stage->observationEncad = $request->input('observationEncad');
        $stage->type = $request->input('type');
        $stage->element_pedagogique_id = $request->input('element_pedagogique_id');
        $stage->axe_stage_id = $request->input('axe_stage_id');
        $stage->offre_id = $request->input('offre_id');
        $stage->convention_id = $request->input('convention_id');
        $stage->individu_id = $request->input('individu_id');
        $stage->encadrant_id = $request->input('encadrant_id');



        if ($stage->save()) <---- THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
        return redirect()->route('admin.stage.edit', ['stage' => $stage])
            ->with('success', 'Enregistrement mis à jour avec succès');
    else
        return redirect()->route('admin.stage.edit', ['stage' => $stage])
            ->with('error', 'Une erreur s\'est produite lors de la mise à jour de l\'enregistrement');
    }
```

I tried `FIND()` instead of `FIRST()` and also `FIRSTORFAIL` and `FINDORFAIL`, nothing works.